# run Yii2 mailing(rendered with a template) through cronjob

Tags: php, cron, yii2, command-line-interface

I render a php layout file with some variables, then I mail it to some address. There is no problem when doing this task through the web. I just call some  controller->action and everything is ok.

Additionally, I want to send a mail whenever its time is set to sent. Cronjob will read a timestamp of email column from db and sends when its time is come.

But the thing is `Yii::$app->mailer->compose('some layout file path here')` uses `output_buffering` internally. Its ok for php that runs on `web`, but it does not work for php that runs on `CLI`. output_buffering can't be turned on `php cli`. Cronjob uses `php cli` not `php web`.

I got stuck, what can I do? Any suggestions? Is it possible to create controller and run action of it? I have one solution: run `curl` with cronjob and access action of controller which runs on web through cli, but its not the best way I think as it overloads the web part.

Please give me the best, fast and not overloading way to do this

Comment: Are you sure? I always send email using SwiftMail in a Console Controller, running jobs with cronjob.

Comment: but it is not simple mail. My emails are with "Layout". It uses `output_buffer`. Do you know what I am talking about?

Comment: Why should not output buffer  work on CLI? Maybe you have disabled it in php.ini.